# Permission Drupal folders

Tags: users, files, media

I create a  [website](http://devel.drupaleasy.ir/amad-bsco)  on Linux/Apache and I want move it to Windows/IIS 6  [here](http://amad-bsco.com) , my panel is Plesk.
I can't upload files and images and my Images that customize with Imagechach module not shown!
I guess folder permission not trust.
where I can find a list of Drupal folder permission?I don't know how to set permission in Plesk,Please help me ..!? :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most directories and files in a stock Drupal environment just need read/execute for the IIS user - this allows IIS/PHP to read and execute the .php, .inc, and other files. For your "files" directory - typically in sites/default/files - IIS will also need write permissions, so it can write uploaded files and create new files (for instance, ImageCache derivatives).

As for how to do this in Plesk, it will vary, but here's a guide that should get you pointed in the right direction (depending on your host, some of the user/group names may differ, but should be close):

http://knowledge.3essentials.com/web-hosting/article/478/Setting-file-folder-permissions-from-Plesk-control-panel-for-Windows.html

Comment: can you help me?!
I give you User and Password my host,and you set permission for me !Inevitably :(

Comment: do you see two sites?do you think this problem about permission?

Comment: see  http://i55.tinypic.com/9jodgw.jpg
and http://i55.tinypic.com/s33of7.jpg

Comment: Looks ok on first glance but I'm neither an IIS expert nor have I ever used Plesk. Create a simple .php file with the contents:

Create a php info file under your webroot, access it from a browser, and see what user/group it's run as. That'll tell you for sure what user IIS is running PHP scripts under. Now make sure that user has full r/w to your files directory.